# Use of the inequality $A \succeq B^{\dagger}$ when B is not invertible

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse, linear-matrix-inequality

In semi-definite programming (SDP), you might have an optimization problem where $A \succeq B^{-1}⪰0$ is a constraint, which implies that $A_{ii} \geq (B^{-1})_{ii}$ for all $i$. In some cases, $B$ may not be invertible, and to handle such situations, I'm considering the use of the Moore-Penrose inverse of $B$, $B^{\dagger}$.

Here's a concrete example to illustrate my concern:

Let's say we have matrix $B$ as follows:

$B = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Computing the pseudo-inverse of $B$, we get:

$B^{\dagger} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -0.5 & -0.5 \\
-0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
-0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}$

**Observation:** The diagonal entries of $B^{\dagger}$ appear to be smaller than expected, which is contrary to the intuition that some of them should be large.

My query is whether the inequality $A_{ii} \geq (B^{\dagger})_{ii}$ still holds for this non-invertible matrix $B$. (For the sake of argument, assume $B\neq0$.) If this inequality remains valid, it would provide a valuable insight for handling such cases in mathematical modeling.